# Asihttp requests not working in ios9

Tags: xcode, afnetworking, ios9, asihttprequest

Hi am using Asihttp request classes in my app,i know its deprecated and need to switch to afnetworking or something new but this is an old project which am continuing and it was working fine with ios8 but doesn't work with ios9. 
Is there any  thing i need to set in build settings or any library to add. Please let me know.

Answer (score 2):

App Transport Security is a feature that improves the security of connections between an app and web services. The feature consists of default connection requirements that conform to best practices for secure connections. Apps can override this default behavior and turn off transport security.

Transport security is available in iOS 9.0 or later, and in OS X v10.11 and later.

To solve your issue please update your .plist file.

1. Add a NSAppTransportSecurity : Dictionary.
2. Add Subkey named " NSAllowsArbitraryLoads " as Boolean : YES

[image]

Comment: Hi i have added these properties in plist it works well when debuggin but fails when run from ipa or test flight. Do you know why this could happen.

Comment: And am not getting NS in the above mentioned default properties could there be any issue with my xcode 7.

Comment: if you are not getting the value from the default list just add it manually.